# css causing white space at the end of the page

Tags: css

I have a problem of howto remove the white space caused on the bottom of the page - when i remove the gear image it works fine.

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size:10pt;
}



.footer_fg{
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width:455px;
  height:358px;
  background: url('/include/images/Final-Website2_11a.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  top: -150px;
  border:0;
}
```

this is the CSS for the site.

Comment: Can you show us HTML code? Also, is this a live website, can you post a link?

Comment: Please put your code on jsfiddle

Comment: I don't see your html, but you can bet that the problem is the `top: -150px;`

Answer (score 0):

Using position: relative it is not the same as margin-top. position:relative first places the item on it's original position (and messures the size of the parent element with this position) and then just moves it. So there will always be white space where this item was before. If you just want to move it without leaving this white space you should think about using margin-top: -150px instead. As we don't see the rest of your code it is hard to tell if this would work for your site.